# What Yahoo Pipes regex use in this case?

Tags: regex, pipe, yahoo

have you any ideas how to change in item. description in Yahoo.pipes this link

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/img/pc/image.gif" class="big" style="background-image:url(http://mysite.com/pre_big_crop/pic/pc/gallery/dd/c1/example.jpeg);" alt="" title="">
```

to this

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/pre_big_crop/pic/pc/gallery/dd/c1/example.jpeg"/>
```

using regex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what variant of RegEx Pipes uses, so I'll go with the .NET variant and you can adjust for whatever syntax is needed. It should be pretty close.

Search for:

```
<img[^>]+url\(
([^\)]+)
\)[^>]+>
```

Replace with:

```
<img src="$1" />
```

Join the lines. Line 1 finds an image tag up to the url argument in the CSS style attribute. Line 2 matches the background image URL and captures it. Line 3 matches the rest of the image tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extremely simple regex to accomplish what you're looking for using PERL style Regexs:

```
<img.*background-image:url\((.*)\);.*>
```

Basically, here is the breakdown on how it matches:

1. It will start by matching the characters "

   It then matches any characters, between 0 and unlimited times.

   Then it matches the string "background-image:url(

   Then it matches any characters, between 0 and unlimited times, which is captured into backreference #1

   Then it matches the characters ");"

   Then it matches any characters, between 0 and unlimited times.

   Then it matches the ">" character.

Note: You should replace the items that match any characters to something more specific, depending on the application that you're using the regex. This is why I've referred to this as "extremely simple".

Then, that gets replaced with:

```
<img src="$1">
```

Edit: Didn't see richardtallent's answer, pretty similar application just a different implementation.

Comment: Yes, they are similar, but there are some minor issues in your pattern: if the input has more than one IMG tag on the same line, only the *last* tag's background image will be captured. Also, if the line also happens to contain another `)` after the last background url, the capture will contain more than just the URL. Both of these are due to `.*` being too greedy (at least it is in .NET, been a LONG while since I've done any regex in Perl).